# Dynamically change Images when current locale changed

Tags: qt, qml, locale, translation, qtquick2

The interface of simple video player, which consists of `Video` and `Image` items, blended by `Blend` from `QtGraphicalEffects`. `Image` has associated `MouseArea` and translucent graphical buttons with "hardcoded" text in English. Default images provided by `QQuickImageProvider` from following locations:

```
import QtQml 2.2

import QtQuick 2.9
import QtMultimedia 5.9

import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Blend {
    id: blender

    mode: "normal"

    property alias playbackState: video.playbackState

    onVisibleChanged: {
        if (!visible) {
            video.playlist.clear()
        }
    }

    source: Video {
        id: video

        visible: false

        width: blender.width
        height: blender.height

        fillMode: VideoOutput.Stretch

        playlist: Playlist {
            onErrorChanged: {
                if (error() !== Playlist.NoError) {
                    console.log("Error: %1 (%2)".arg(error()).arg(errorString()))
                    video.stop()
                }
            }

            function nextInLoop() {
                currentIndex = (currentIndex + itemCount + 1) % itemCount
            }

            function previousInLoop() {
                currentIndex = (currentIndex + itemCount - 1) % itemCount
            }
        }

        Connections {
            target: videoPlayerSingleton
            onSetPlaylist: {
                if (video.playlist.clear()) {
                    if (video.playlist.addItems(playlist)) {
                        if (index < 0) {
                            video.playlist.playbackMode = Playlist.Random
                        } else {
                            video.playlist.currentIndex = index
                            video.playlist.playbackMode = Playlist.Sequential
                        }
                        video.play()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        autoPlay: true
        loops: MediaPlayer.Infinite
    }

    foregroundSource: Image {
        visible: false

        width: blender.width
        height: blender.height

        sourceSize: Qt.size(width, height)
        source: {
            switch (playbackState) {
            case MediaPlayer.PlayingState : return "image://videoplayer/pause"
            case MediaPlayer.PausedState : return "image://videoplayer/play"
            case MediaPlayer.StoppedState : return "image://videoplayer/logo"
            }
        }
        smooth: true
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        readonly property rect previousButton: Qt.rect((130 - 40) / 1920, (505 - 40) / 1080, 80 / 1920, 80 / 1080)
        readonly property rect nextButton: Qt.rect((1800 - 40) / 1920, (505 - 40) / 1080, 80 / 1920, 80 / 1080)
        readonly property rect playPauseButton: Qt.rect((950 - 40) / 1920, (980 - 40) / 1080, 80 / 1920, 80 / 1080)
        readonly property rect backToCatalogButton: Qt.rect((1510 - 40) / 1920, (980 - 40) / 1080, 80 / 1920, 80 / 1080)
        readonly property rect openCollectionButton: Qt.rect((1710 - 40) / 1920, (980 - 40) / 1080, 80 / 1920, 80 / 1080)

        onClicked: {
            var hit = Qt.point(mouse.x / width, mouse.y / height)
            if (videoPlayerSingleton.contains(previousButton, hit)) {
                video.playlist.previousInLoop()
            } else if (videoPlayerSingleton.contains(nextButton, hit)) {
                video.playlist.nextInLoop()
            } else if (videoPlayerSingleton.contains(playPauseButton, hit)) {
                if (playbackState === MediaPlayer.PlayingState) {
                    video.pause()
                } else {
                    video.play()
                }
            } else if (videoPlayerSingleton.contains(backToCatalogButton, hit)) {
                videoPlayerSingleton.backToCatalog(video.playlist.currentIndex)
            } else if (videoPlayerSingleton.contains(openCollectionButton, hit)) {
                videoPlayerSingleton.openCollection(video.playlist.currentIndex)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is also corresponding images in `+ru_RU/` subfolder into the resources.

C++ `QObject` singletone from global context may have signal `void languageChanged(QLocale locale);`, which emitted, when all the `QTranslator`s are replaced in `QCoreApplication::removeTranslator/installTranslator` for each of loaded resource.

```
// i18n.hpp:

#pragma once

#include <QtCore>

Q_DECLARE_LOGGING_CATEGORY(i18nCategory)

#ifndef PROJECT_DEFAULT_LOCALE
#define PROJECT_DEFAULT_LOCALE "ru_RU"
#endif

class Internationalization
        : public QObject
{

    Q_OBJECT

    static QMutex mutex;
    static Internationalization * self;

    explicit Internationalization(QString projectName = QStringLiteral(PROJECT_NAME));

public :

    static
    Internationalization * instance()
    {
        Q_ASSERT(qApp);
        QMutexLocker lock{&mutex};
        if (!self) {
            self = ::new Internationalization;
        }
        return self;
    }

    void setDependencies(QStringList dependencies);

public Q_SLOTS :

    void load(QLocale locale = QStringLiteral(PROJECT_DEFAULT_LOCALE));

Q_SIGNALS :

    void aboutToLanguageChanged();
    void languageChanged(QLocale locale);

private :

    QStringList translations;
    QList< QPointer< QTranslator > > translators;

};

#define i18n Internationalization::instance()

// i18n.cpp:

#include "i18n.hpp"

Q_LOGGING_CATEGORY(i18nCategory, "internationalization")

QMutex Internationalization::mutex;
Internationalization * Internationalization::self = Q_NULLPTR;

Internationalization::Internationalization(QString projectName)
    : QObject{qApp}
{
    translations.prepend(projectName);
    translations.prepend(PROJECT_NAME);
}

void Internationalization::setDependencies(QStringList dependencies)
{
    translations << dependencies;
}

void Internationalization::load(QLocale locale)
{
    // get_target_property(QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE Qt5::qmake IMPORTED_LOCATION)
    // qmake -query QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS
    Q_ASSERT(!(translators.size() > translations.size()));
    while (translators.size() < translations.size()) {
        translators << ::new QTranslator{qApp};
    }
    Q_EMIT aboutToLanguageChanged();
    QLocale::setDefault(locale);
    QMutableListIterator translator{translators};
    for (const auto translation : translations) {
        Q_ASSERT(translator.hasNext());
        const auto t = translator.next();
        if (!QCoreApplication::removeTranslator(t)) {
            if (!t->isEmpty()) {
                qCDebug(i18nCategory).noquote()
                        << tr("Unable to remove translation from project %1")
                           .arg(translation);
            }
        }
        if (t->load(locale, translation, ".", ":/i18n")) {
            if (!QCoreApplication::installTranslator(t)) {
                qCDebug(i18nCategory).noquote()
                        << tr("Unable to install translation for %1 locale from project %2")
                           .arg(locale.name(), translation);
            }
        } else {
            qCDebug(i18nCategory).noquote()
                    << tr("Unable to load translation for %1 locale from project %2")
                       .arg(locale.name(), translation);
        }
    }
    Q_EMIT languageChanged(locale);
}
```

I want to change locations of images on signal which emitted along with locale changing. Is it possible to change selected files at runtime (i.e. w/o recreating of the parent `Item`, which contains `VideoPlayer`)?

Connected question: what is affected by file selectors first: `QImageReader`'s filepaths used internally into `QQuickImageProvider` or `source:` of *Quick*'s `Image`? The latter are derived from the first. Or maybe both?

Comment: Have you tried setting Image `cached` property to `false`, toggle the Image `visible` property `false` then `true` again?

Comment: Also you should use a simpler expression on the Image `source`. Pass the `playbackState` and locale variables to the QQuickImageProvider, and then the bindings will take care of refreshing the Image when either variable changes

Comment: @MarkCh Are you sure, that QQuickImageProvider is feasible from QML side? Anyways suggested workflow is not proper for using QQuickImageProvider I think. It works only with filepath urls only with specific scheme ("image"). QQuickImageProvider is just a convenience abstraction layer, which should not be visible from QML side.

Comment: @MarkCh <<Also you should use a simpler expression on the Image source>> what you can suggest for enum to replace switch/case?

Comment: Okay I think I understand what you want now. I will extend my answer to use locale and enums, and then we can discuss again.

Answer (score 1):

The approach is to assign your locale to a QML property, and then use that and the video playbackState enum property in a binding expression to the `source` property of the `Image` item.

When the button is clicked, the QML locale property is changed, and the binding expression on the `source` of the `Image` item is automatically re-evaluated, causing the QQuickImageProvider to serve a new image.

### main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtMultimedia 5.9

ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Video {
        id: video
    }

    Column {
        id: contents

        property bool toggle: false

        function toggleLocale() {
            if (toggle) {
                // set QML locale
                applicationWindow.locale = Qt.locale("en_GB")
            } else {
                // set QML locale
                applicationWindow.locale = Qt.locale("ru_RU")
            }

            toggle = !toggle
        }

        Text { text: "locale %1".arg(applicationWindow.locale.name) }
        Text { text: "playbackState %1".arg(video.playbackState) }

        Button { text: "toggle locale"; onClicked: contents.toggleLocale() }

        Image {
            source: "image://colors/%1/%2".arg(applicationWindow.locale.name).arg(video.playbackState)
        }
    }
}
```

### imageprovider.h

```
#ifndef IMAGEPROVIDER_H
#define IMAGEPROVIDER_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <QImage>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QQuickImageProvider>

class ImageProvider : public QQuickImageProvider
{
public:
    ImageProvider()
        : QQuickImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider::Image)
    {
    }

    QImage requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
    {
        Q_UNUSED(requestedSize)

        QString localePath = id.split("/").at(0);
        QString fileName;

        int playbackState = id.split("/").at(1).toInt();
        switch (playbackState) {
        case QMediaPlayer::StoppedState:
            fileName = "logo.png";
            break;
        case QMediaPlayer::PlayingState:
            fileName = "play.png";
            break;
        case QMediaPlayer::PausedState:
            fileName = "pause.png";
            break;
        default:
            fileName = "logo.png";
            break;
        }

        // the following images are located under resources:
        // en_GB/logo.png
        // en_GB/play.png
        // en_GB/pause.png
        // ru_RU/logo.png
        // ru_RU/play.png
        // ru_RU/pause.png
        // which is why imagePath starts with : colon
        // but they could also be on the filesystem
        QString imagePath = QString(":%1/%2").arg(localePath).arg(fileName);
        qDebug() << "return Image file:" << imagePath;

        QImage image(imagePath);
        *size = image.size();

        // QImage supports copy, so can return like this
        // copy is returned, original on the stack is destroyed
        return image;
    }
};

#endif // IMAGEPROVIDER_H
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "imageprovider.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.addImageProvider(QLatin1String("colors"), new ImageProvider());

    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Your code differs substantially from what I ask. Namely the locale changing is important. Your simplification in fact is oversimplification. Changing just image name is orthogonal to what I want. I want to change image source silently, just using the very suitable `QFileSelector` machinery.

Comment: BTW your code is close to what I seen into the standard Qt examples.

Comment: Oh no! My eyes bleeding!

Comment: It is architectural misconception to put some hardcoded strings into implementation details of *generic* image provider. What if I sometimes decide to add `image://videoplayer/forward` and `image://videoplayer/rewind`? Why should I need to go to implementation details of some class into C++ code? I just want to put a file into corresponding location and link it from QML code specifying just URL.

Comment: What if `size` is `nullptr`?

Comment: Your hard-coded strings are in QML, mine are in C++, what's the difference?

Comment: <<QImage supports copy, so can return like this
        // copy is returned, original on the stack is destroyed>> is not true. `QImage` is implicitly shared, so payload would be just transferred.

Comment: Because *image provider* is like a server. Almost non-mutable code. C++ part of application is just a glue. How can I get `playbackState`? Where is it? Do you think it is better to pass it from QML side to C++ side in global variable?

Comment: If you want to do it that way. QQuickImageProvider can do anything you want it to. And you can have as many different ones as you choose. In our project we aim to keep the QML as simple as possible. If the QQuickImageProvider provider can be made to do more work in order to simplify other parts of the code , then that's what we choose to do. I'm sorry if you don't like this approach.

Comment: `playbackState` is passed as second argument inside the `id` after the locale.

Comment: Yes there are error cases that need handling. My aim was not to provide perfect code which you could copy and paste into your application.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Don't think this is my way.

Comment: Current locale name is already can be obtained by `QLocale{}.name()` on C++ side. I don't want to pass this specifically as a part of virtual filename. Also passing encoded `playbackState` to C++ side along with locale name, then decoding on C++ side is superfluous. Bad decision. I prefer to deal with that on QML side. If can't, then I deliver that on C++ side.

Comment: Qml Applicationwindow locale is different to C++ and system locale. So it could be set using the QLocale::setDefault() and accessed globally that way. All I have been trying to demonstrate is that by passing all the variables in as arguments, then the QML engine can use the bindings in order to take care of the image updating from the QQuickImageProvider without you having to connect any extra signals or force any manual updates. I accept there are different ways of achieving the same thing, there always are with QML!

Comment: Why you ignore `QFileSelector`? It is intended for this task exactly.

Comment: If I have to use intrusive approach, then better I stick [this approach](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_do_dynamic_translation_in_QML). Just add empty string to fixed string on QML side and handle locale name on behalf of image provider's QFileSelector.

Comment: Seems like you don't really need QQuickImageProvider then, for what you are trying to do. Just construct the filepath how you want to do it and then apply the string to the `source` of the `Image{}` item. Why even bother to use a QQuickImageProvider if it will only be dumb/passthrough and serve up the filename you pass into it?

Comment: Image provider can switch URL scheme at runtime, say from resources `:/images/videoplayer` to current directory subdir: `images/videoplayer` depending on, say, some `QSettings` value.

Comment: So can `Image` by switching the `qrc:///` and `file:` prefixes used to construct the source urls